# c# linq where on object lists incredibly slow

Tags: c#, linq, master-detail

i have a setup that looks like this

```
foreach(Master m in masters){
   m.details = allDetails.Where(d => d.ID == m.detailID).ToList();
}
```

masters and AllDetails are just Lists of objects, no actual SQL being run here. I did that earlier. I actually didnt write a "normal" sql join query, because i expected this way to be rather fast...

This runs incredibly slow, as in 20s+ for like 20k master entries.

I know i must be missing something incredibly obvious, but i just cant figure out what. Whats the way to solve this super common problem?

Comment: A select where run in the db would be **much** faster. And, for all we know, you haven't materialized `allDetails` and so, for every master, you're hitting the DB. To prevent this, when you create `allDetails` do a .ToArray() on your queryable.

Comment: I think the normal join will be quick because it will create a master ID hash and a allDetails hash. The join will run slow only if you don't have enough memory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For each `Master` you iterate through the whole `allDetails` list. You should use grouping and create a dictionary:

```
var detailsPerMaster = allDetails.GroupBy(d => d.ID)
                                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
```

Then you can set your `details` properties:

```
foreach(Master m in masters)        
    m.details = detailsPerMaster[m.detailID];
```

Or to better match your results:

```
foreach(Master m in masters)            
    m.details = detailsPerMaster.TryGetValue(m.detailID, out var list) ? list : new List<--detailTypeHere-->();
```

Comment: jesus christ, that improved my time from 20000ms to 6. six.
So whats the lesson here? If i prefer to do my object joining in c# rather than sql, always query Dictionaries? Is there a difference if i know the relationship is 1-1?

Comment: @DFENS From your question it's not clear which part is executed or can be executed by a database. Anyway, the main problem in your code is that you iterate the whole details collection for every master again and again. In may solution you only iterate the details once while building groups. So you gain performance no matter if it's done by the db or your client. The dictionary is only there to have an easy way to propagate the results into the master instances.

Comment: The dictionary adds a good amount of performance too. I checked the normal FirstOrDefault vs creating a Dict, and its about 4 times faster. I guess the main takeaway for me is to avoid Where, whenever possible. And that im most likely doing something wrong if anything ever takes over a couple of seconds.